# Flutter, how to catch API data quickly changing with a limited api requests

Tags: flutter, api

I have Riot Games Development API which has "20 requests every 1 seconds(s) and 100 requests every 2 minutes(s)". and i'm trying to make an app that notifies me when the game has started by checking "gameStartTime" value of current game data every 2 or 3 seconds until the game starts.(it returns a value of 0 until the game starts and returns an epoch time when the game is started.)
The problem is that this "gameStartTime" value does change to the epoch time when the game is started, but goes back to 0 after a few seconds. so when i test my app, it sometimes does not notify me when it should. I feel like i should make the request more often to catch the value before it goes to 0, but am worried about the api limit. I would love to get advice on this issue.

these are the codes i used to get data from Riot Games API:

```
class MakeRequestScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String? derivedId;
  MakeRequestScreen({this.derivedId});
  // Declare a field that holds the Todo.

  @override
  _MakeRequestScreenState createState() => _MakeRequestScreenState();
}

class _MakeRequestScreenState extends State<MakeRequestScreen> {
  late Stream<InGameData> myStream;
  InGameDataDecoder myData = InGameDataDecoder();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    myStream = myData.getData(id: widget.derivedId, url: inGameDataUrl);
    setUpTimedFetch();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('해피로딩'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              StreamBuilder<InGameData>(
                  stream: myStream,
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.data == null) {
                      return Text(
                        'Looking for your match,,,',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0),
                      );
                    } else {
                      switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                        case ConnectionState.none:
                          return Text('Select a lot');
                        case ConnectionState.waiting:
                          return Expanded(
                              child:
                                  Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()));
                        case ConnectionState.active:
                          if (snapshot.data!.gameStartTime.toString().length >
                                  3 &&
                              snapshot.data!.gameStartTime.toString().length !=
                                  0) {
                            return Expanded(
                                child: Center(
                                    child: Text(
                              'Your game has started.',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 30.0,
                                color: Colors.greenAccent,
                              ),
                            )));
                          }
                          if (snapshot.data!.gameStartTime.toString() == '0') {
                            return Text(
                              'Got into loading screen!',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 30.0,
                                color: Colors.yellow,
                              ),
                            );
                          }
                          return Text('hmm,,,');
                        case ConnectionState.done:
                          return Text('done');
                      }
                    }
                  })
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  setUpTimedFetch() {
    Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 2), (timer) {
      setState(() {
        // maybe i need to make this function repeated
        myStream = myData.getData(id: widget.derivedId, url: inGameDataUrl);
      });
    });
  }
}
```

classes being used:

```
class InGameData {
  final int? gameStartTime;

  InGameData({required this.gameStartTime});

  factory InGameData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return InGameData(gameStartTime: json['gameStartTime']);
  }
}

class InGameDataDecoder {
  Stream<InGameData> getData(
      {required String? id, required String url}) async* {
    http.Response response =
        await http.get(Uri.parse('$url$id?api_key=$apiKey'));

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      yield* Stream.periodic(Duration(seconds: 2), (int abc) {
        return InGameData.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
      });
    } else {
      throw Exception('exception');
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case you would usually use a `Webhook` which is basically a reverse API. You would provide a URL which is called by the Riot Games server to notify you when a game has started. If that feature is not provided by Riot, then there is not much you can do.

Your problem is a common limitation of this kind of APIs.

Edit: From a short look at the Riot API I couldn't find such a feature.